# C# How to replace multiple chars in string at the same time?

Tags: c#, string, replace, char

I have a problem. I'm making the `1337 7r4|\|5l4704 (leet speak translator)` and i want to have multiple chars to replace with one other.

for example I want to replace "A" and "a" with "4" in one command. I have something like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = "";
        string a = textBox1.Text;
        string sr = a.Replace("A", "4");
        textBox2.Text = sr;
    }
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
string sr = a.Replace('A', '4').Replace('a', '4');
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The OP asks `for example I want to replace "A" and "a" with "4" in one command`, which my answer addresses. Unless you mean `Replace` daisy chained means more than one command.